# How can I (from a SalesOrderEntity) retrieve the shipping address?

Tags: c#, magento, soap

I'm using SOAP through Visual Studio 2012 RC with C# to use the Magento API. I did this by adding a service reference pointing to the SOAP WSDL file.

Now, I'm having difficulties getting the shipping address of a SalesOrderEntity. Here's how I retrieve these entities.

```
var f = new filters();
f.filter = new associativeEntity[] { 
    new associativeEntity {
        key ="status", 
        value ="processing"
    }
};
var entities = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, f);
```

This works just great, but when I iterate through them and display some of their information, I stumble upon something strange.

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{

    //the following line crashes for some strange reason.
    //the error is SoapHeaderException: Address not exists.
    var info = mservice.customerAddressInfo(mlogin, int.Parse(entity.shipping_address_id));

    Debug.WriteLine(info.firstname);
}
```

The shipping address is not `0`, has indeed been set to a proper number (and yes, it's a string for some weird reason although it always represents a number).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address is stored in a `salesOrderAddressEntity`, which is inside the `salesOrderEntity`.

```
var magento = new MagentoService();
var session = magento.login("LOGIN", "APIKEY");

var order = magento.salesOrderInfo(session, "100029631");

var address = order.shipping_address;

Console.WriteLine(address.firstname + " " + address.lastname);
Console.WriteLine(address.street);
Console.WriteLine(address.postcode + " " + address.city);
```